# Larvel Sail: Installing Composer Dependencies For Existing Applications on Apple Silicon M1 Fails

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, apple-m1, laravel-sail

I cloned an existing application on a machine with Apple's M1 processor. Then used following command to bring it ([Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects)).

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php74-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Then also tried:

```
docker run --rm --platform linux/amd64 \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php74-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Both of these commands fail with same message:

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception

  could not find driver

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18
     14▕ final class Exception extends PDOException
     15▕ {
     16▕     public static function new(\PDOException $exception): self
     17▕     {
  ➜  18▕         return new self($exception);
     19▕     }
     20▕ }
     21▕

      +1 vendor frames
  2   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))

      +18 vendor frames
  21  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:94
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("listen")
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

However, I can execute `php artisan package:discover --ansi` command from both host machine and inside container:

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan package:discover --ansi
["select * from `data_types`",[],79.14]
Discovered Package: arrilot/laravel-widgets
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: kreait/laravel-firebase
Discovered Package: larapack/doctrine-support
Discovered Package: larapack/voyager-hooks
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: lexxyungcarter/chatmessenger
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: tcg/voyager
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Any help with this issue is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? `could not find driver` is usually thrown when the driver for the configured database is not installed. This is **not** a problem of Composer, but of your application

Comment: Laravel Sail uses Docker containers. On x86 processors, Laravel Sail works just fine. The issue is not with my application but with Laravel Sail or Docker when running on Apple Silicone.

Comment: Most likely the problem is with laravelsail/php74-composer:latest image on M1 processors.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Which database do you use? Which drivers are installed?

Comment: Only thing I found was to add  --platform linux/amd64 flag. Not sure if you are aware but docker containers are like virtual machines. When you run a docker image, it should have everything it needs including all drivers. 

I am using MySQL, and MySQL docker images do have issues on M1 processors. I had to use a specific version of MySQL in my docker-compose file. 

Tonight, I will test with brand a new Laravel project. If it still fails, I may open an issue on Laravel Sail repo. If not, it maybe issue specific to my project.

Comment: I use Docker every day. As far as I see in the Dockerfiles at https://hub.docker.com/r/laravelsail/php74-composer/tags, that image does not contain any MySQL related stuff. Also, did you ensure that the MySQL container you refer to is started on using `docker run`? How do you start it otherwise?

Comment: In this case, we should not need to start a MySQL container since the whole purpose of this command is to install dependencies. I am not even sure why it need database for this step but now I think something is wrong in my `composer.json`. I just created a brand new project and dependency installation worked.

Comment: If you run scripts during the package installation, anything can happen. If you want to avoid that, use the `no-scripts` flag

Comment: Thank you, this flag worked. Now anyone else can clone and install my project on M1 machines and install dependencies with docker and without needing to install PHP locally. Maybe you want to submit this as an answer, here is the full command: ```docker run --rm --platform linux/amd64 \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php74-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the following command, only one pretty specific container is started:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php74-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The container contains everything that is needed to run Composer - but not much more. It might not contain all PHP extensions needed to run your application, nor will the command start other containers that provide dependencies for your application, like a database container.

If you solely run the steps needed to install your application's dependencies, everything will work. But if you also use Composer's script functionalities, this can cause problems, as some scripts might expect that any PHP extension is installed in the runtime environment, or any depending container is also started.

In your case, at least one PHP extension to run your application is missing:

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception

  could not find driver
```

That script tries to open a database connection, but can not find the extension that is needed for this connection, as `laravelsail/php74-composer` does **not** contain any database driver.

---

**Solution**: run `composer install`  with the additional flag `--no-scripts`.

Comment: Solved my issue perfectly with --no-scripts as I just need to install stuff on my M1 so I can use sail.  Thanks, upvoted.